# Hp VuGen 11.5 Basic Correlation blank value

Tags: c, alm, vugen

This should be a really simple fix that I simply can’t figure out and need help. I have a script that records the submission of a record. This record submission generates a unique ID when the user clicks the submit button. The ID that is generated is used for the new form.

In the past I could simply use ‘web_reg_save_param’ and the value would be saved. However, in this case the value is not given until the record is submitted. So I can’t capture it from the URL as I’ve done in the past.

The following what is recorded and then I’ve included what I’ve tried and the warning message in the debug. Please let me know if there is any further clarification that is needed.

Thank you in advance.

```
web_submit_data("subpage", 
"Action=somewebsite.com/subpage", 
"Method=POST", 
"RecContentType=text/html", 
"Referer=somewebsite.com/subpage?id=xxxxx1", 
"Mode=HTML", 
ITEMDATA, 
//this value is what I need to be correlated 
"Name=recordID", "Value=c39d54a59112fcb223978bb6869d47d2", ENDITEM, 
//other values that are present on the form which can be reused
"Name=variable", "Value=someValue", ENDITEM, 
LAST);

I've tried to do the following - 

web_reg_save_param("ID","LB=recordID=","RB=&","Search=All","NotFound=ERROR",LAST);
web_submit_data("subpage", 
"Action=somewebsite.com/subpage", 
"Method=POST", 
"RecContentType=text/html", 
"Referer=somewebsite.com/subpage?id=xxxxx1", 
"Mode=HTML", 
ITEMDATA, 
//this value is what I need to be correlated 
"Name=recordID", "Value={ID}", ENDITEM, 
//other values that are present on the form which can be reused
"Name=variable", "Value=someValue", ENDITEM, 
LAST);

But the "ID" is coming up as blank. 
Warning: The string 'ID' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use:

```
    web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=recordID",
    "LB=id=\"id\" value=\"",
    "RB=\" type",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/subpage*",
    LAST);
```